# How to programmatically access Gradle plugin dependencies from within plugin itself?

Tags: hadoop, gradle

I'm working on a Hadoop testing Gradle plugin. In mini-YARN cluster mode, Hadoop adds everything in `java.class.path` to the environment of the spawned subprocesses. In order for the subprocess to run properly, certain Hadoop jars need to be on the classpath.

Even though my plugin declares `compile` dependencies on the required Hadoop jars, when the buildscript of a project applying the plugin is executed, `java.class.path` is set to `/.../gradle-2.3/lib/gradle-launcher-2.3.jar` and does not contain any of the Hadoop jars, causing the subprocesses to fail.

I would thus like my plugin to programmatically access its own `compile` dependencies and add them to `java.class.path` at runtime. Is this possible?

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want access to the buildscript dependencies of the project applying my plugin; I want access to the plugin's buildscript dependencies.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: For example, I have my plugin defined in the buildSrc folder, and the plugin's build.gradle file has a "compile" dependency on a Hadoop jar. How do I programmatically access this dependency from within the plugin's Java code?

Comment: Do you have an SSCCE online somewhere? Ready to run?

Answer (score 0):

When your plugin is applied you obtain a reference to an instance of the `Project` class. With this reference you can get the project dependencies (seems that this is not what you ate looking for) as well as the dependencies of the build script itself. It can be done in the following way:

```
project.buildscript.dependencies
```

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getBuildscript()) is where the journey begins.